# not able to call function on click or change of dropdown menu (angularjs, xeditablejs)

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I'm using angularjs and xeditablejs to show dropdown menu on a table (while adding a new row). Now, after selecting a drop down - I want to autofill next column for that row. But, ng-change or ng-click is not triggering function call to my controller.

Html snippet:

```
<div ng-if="pcMasterData" class="ng-cloak">
        <b>ProfitCenter Table</b>
        <br />
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" style="width: 40%">
            <tr style="font-weight: bold">
                <td>ProfitCenter Id</td>
                <td>ProfitCenter Description</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in pcMasterData">
                <td>
                    <span editable-select="row.ProfitCenterId" e-name="pcid" e-form="rowform" e-required e-ng-options="pcInfo.ProfitCenterId as pcInfo.ProfitCenterId for pcInfo in pcInfoArray" ng-model="kkPcId" ng-change="setPcDescription(kkPcId)">
                        {{row.ProfitCenterId}}
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span e-name="pcdescription" e-form="rowform">
                        {{row.ProfitCenterDescription || pcDescription}}
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

JS snippet:

```
        $scope.setPcDescription = function (pcId) {
        alert("[here-" + pcId + "]");
        // filter data from infoArray
        $scope.pcDescription = getDescriptionFromArray(pcId, infoArray);
    };
```

Here, setPcDescription() is not getting called at all!

==========================================

**update 1**:
I used e-ng-change="setPcDescription($data)" instead and now, this function gets called. here $data is pcId. So, I have to do a look up for description using infoArray. But, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in an ng-repeat block you are in the scope created by ng-repeat which doesn't have the setPcDescription you are looking for.

You can use $parent.setPcDescription() but that is not recommended as you will have to keep track how many scopes above your function is from where you are referencing it.

If you use controllerAs syntax, [(Awesome article by Todd Motto)](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/), you will be able to reference the controller function easier and consistently.